# Network error while browse on internet on brave browser?

Tags: networking

Why do I keep getting `ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED` error in the brave browser when a website loads initially but when I reload the page everything will work most of the time no matter how many times I visit the webpage and when I try to download something on brave my downloading failed instantly, can anybody help me?

btw, I'm using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Are you using a VPN?

Comment: Well yes, I'm using proton VPN, but it is currently disabled!

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: what exactly do I have to look at in `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` command output?